# What does findViewById(android.R.id.content) do in Snackbar?

Tags: java, android

I have seen in Snackbars being passed this `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` argument. We can't pass `getContext()` method as it demands a `View` parameter. I have seen on internet that programmers pass this argument inside Snackbar, what does it really mean?

Also, since it asks a `View` argument can i pass like any view that i have in my xml file, for example, any `imageview` or any `videoView`. If i pass these as an arguments, would my code still work? If yes, isn't it a little unexplanatory in code about what's really going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what does it really mean?

It asks the hosting activity to find a widget whose ID is `android.R.id.content`. All activities have one of these, set up by the framework `Activity` implementation and its associated `Window`. It represents the main content area of the activity.

> isn't it a little unexplanatory in code about what's really going on?

You are certainly welcome to add comments to your code to explain your choice.

[The `Snackbar` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar.html#make) explains the role of the `View`:

> Snackbar will try and find a parent view to hold Snackbar's view from the value given to view. Snackbar will walk up the view tree trying to find a suitable parent, which is defined as a CoordinatorLayout or the window decor's content view, whichever comes first.
>
> Having a CoordinatorLayout in your view hierarchy allows Snackbar to enable certain features, such as swipe-to-dismiss and automatically moving of widgets.

With that in mind...

> can i pass like any view that i have in my xml file, for example, any imageview or any videoView. If i pass these as an arguments, would my code still work?

Perhaps. It depends a bit on the UI of your app. If there is a particular `CoordinatorLayout` that you want to use with the `Snackbar`, pass it (or a child) to `make()`. Otherwise, any widget should work.